# htaccess RewriteRule query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my accessories page url

```
http://localhost/motobatt/index.php?route=information/static&p=62&b=59
```

and this page already can access using this url

```
http://localhost/motobatt/accessories
```

but now how to pass those query , url should be like this

```
http://localhost/motobatt/accessories&p=62&b=59
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /motobatt
RewriteRule ^accessories index.php?route=information/static&p=$1&b=$2
```

Comment: The query string is started with a question mark, not an ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `&p=$1&b=$2` bit from your rule. There isn't any capture groups for the `$1` or `$2` to back reference so they'll just end up being blank. What you want is to use the `QSA` flag which will append any existing query string to the end of your rule's target:

```
RewriteBase /motobatt
RewriteRule ^accessories index.php?route=information/static [QSA]
```